# Can't Install corrr package in R 3.5.2

Tags: r, package

Stuck for the moment using `R 3.5.2` (in order to use the `revoscaleR` package). I want to use the `corrr` package but I can't install it.

If I type:

```
install.packages("corrr")
```

It says:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘corrr’ is not available (for R version 3.5.2)
```

If I try to install from `github` (stretching the limits of my knowledge here)

```
library(devtools)
install_github("tidymodels/corrr")
```

it says (at the end of the installation):

```
* installing *source* package 'corrr' ...
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace 'rlang' 0.3.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.4.0 is required
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'corrr'
* removing 'C:/Users/****/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/corrr'
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/****/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpsb21si/file6a068e612e3/corrr_0.4.2.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Can anyone help please?

`****` above is my Windows username of course

Comment: try `install_version`?  Based on the archive (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/corrr/) you could do like `install_version('corrr', '0.3.1')` to see if an older version works with your current versions of R and `rlang`

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but I saw: `Warning in install.packages : 'lib = "0.3.1"' is not writable` followed by a dialog box saying `"would you like to use a personal library instead?"` - unsure what that means

Comment: Hmmm...I tried this again this evening and it worked perfectly. Not sure why...had to go back to 0.3.0 but all is now well. Thank you very much.